# Other elements in list not displaying when replacing the index of other element in the list

Tags: java

I have a list of three elements but when I iterate , I just remove one element and shifting the place of the removed element.

At,that time only the removed element is displayed other elements are not being displayed..

I have provided my code below.

Please, provide me some solution.

```
public class ListRemove {
  public static void main(String []args){
      int i =0;

    List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
    lst.add("Cat");
    lst.add("Dog");
    lst.add("Rat");

   Iterator<String> iterate = lst.iterator();
   while(iterate.hasNext()){
       String str = iterate.next();
       if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("Dog")){
           iterate.remove();
           lst.set(0, str);
           System.out.println(str);
       }
   }

}
```

}

O/p:
Dog

Expected: Dog,Cat,Rat

Comment: You're not supposed to alter a container while you're iterating through it. It screws up stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing why you are getting only Dog as output is because you are having your `System.out.println(str);` statement inside if block which will only run when there is element called **Dog**. For other elements it won't print anything.

Second thing, if you want your output to be Dog, Cat, Rat then you won't get it by using `lst.set(0, str);` because set method will replace the element at position 0. So your Cat element will be replaced by Dog. Therefore you won't get Cat in your output.

[For Info about set method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set%28int,%20E%29)

**EDIT:**

Try with `add()` method in spite of `set()`.

```
while(iterate.hasNext()){
   String str = iterate.next();
   if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("Dog")){
       iterate.remove();
       lst.add(0, str);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ListRemove {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int swapPosition = 0;

    List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
    lst.add("Cat");
    lst.add("Dog");
    lst.add("Rat");

    for(int i=0;i<lst.size();i++){
        if(lst.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("Dog")){
            swapPosition = i;
        }
    }

    Collections.swap(lst, 0, swapPosition);
    System.out.println("Results after swap operation:");
    for(String str: lst){
        System.out.println(str);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: in the place of System.out.println(item), its coming as Dog and Rat.I need Dog Cat Rat

Comment: what is your expected output ?. Right now you are removing the Dog item and setting 0th item as Dog..So remaining will Dog and Rat.

Comment: Dog Cat Rat, below one buddy commented that set(-,-) method will replace but i  dont want Cat to replace by Dog just it has to move to Oth element in list

Comment: You need to find a string in the list and put it in the first position ? Am i right ?

Comment: @Karthik In my answer I explained why you are getting only Dog and Rat. Have you read it?